# git-clone memory allocation error

Tags: git

I'm trying to run git clone and am receiving the following error:

```
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed
fatal: index-pack died with error code 128
fetch-pack from 'user@server:git' failed.
```

I was able to successfully do a clone on my local machine, but it's failing when I try to clone to another server.

Still somewhat new to this whole git thing, so any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I think the fatal is happening on the server; how much memory does the server have? How big is the repo? What's 'git count-objects' say?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "clone **to** another server"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have big files in your repository (like log files for example) ?
Apparently, your repository is too big to be retrieved on your hard drive.

There are two things you can do :

- Check for big files and remove them if they're not useful (not only by committing. But also by [modifying your history](http://book.git-scm.com/5_modifying_your_history.html). If you still have your big files in our repository, it won't be smaller.
- Do a "[git gc](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html)". It'll automatically cleanup unused files and compress the repository.

Comment: git creates a new pack for each clone, containing the relevant objects for the cloner; so, I don't think git gc will help.

Comment: Yeah, we overlooked a large file (in this case a zip archive) that seemed to be causing the problem. That link about modifying the history was a big help. Thanks for that.

Comment: how do you do this on a remote branch?

Comment: You can't manipulate a remote branch without getting it locally.

Comment: git gc also causes this error for me (fatal: Out of memory, calloc failed)

Comment: git gc caused the same error for me until I actually deleted .git and reinitialized. Has something to do with the commit history.

Answer (score 1):

If `git` on the remote machine fails due to memory constraints you might also try `rsync` or `scp` to copy the repository to your local machine and continue with cloning from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the `git clone` command with `--depth -1`. This will only fetch the last commit, so operations that involve history (git log, blame, or even push/pull) may not work. But, it needs less memory usage, disk space, and network transfers.

The limitations are described there: [Why can't I push from a shallow clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your local machine in 32 bits and the other server is 64 bits...
I got a similar issue on Windows using [MSysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) 32 bits.
The git 64 bits from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) did the job.

My [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516065/938111) is available on question [Git on Windows, “Out of memory - malloc failed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903).