# git how to mark a specific subfolder as branch

Tags: git, git-branch, subdirectory

Recently I migrated from SVN to GIT using `git-svn`.

Actual size of checkeded out code is ~24GB. 
In GIT, currently I see only once branch as `origin/master`. Hence if each developer clone master, he need to pull 24GB everytime, which is real pain.

So, I need to Mark some of the existing locations as branches, so that those can be checked out directly, instead of full repo.

project repo structure is like:

```
/Docs/
/project-maintainance/
/main-project/
             /module1
                    /branch1  
                    /branch2  
             /module2
                    /branch1  
                    /branch2
                    /branch3
```

Now, to accomplish this task, I want to Mark some specific folders as branch, instead of creating new branches. I browsed through so many webpages, but it only increased my confusion as I'm a beginner.

How can branches be created from subfolder instead of top level folder?

Edit: Right now my aim is to be able to `checkout multiple subtrees, push and pull changes.`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, git does not work like this as it is a [distributed version control system (DVCS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control_system). This means that you have an entire copy of the code and not just part of it.

However, it is possible to do what is called a `shallow clone`. For example:

```
git clone <repo> --depth 1
```

This approach comes with various caveats - you can find plenty more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone).

Ultimately, 24GB is extremely large for a git repo. In fact I've never heard of such a large repository before. It may be worth investigating trying to drastically reduce it in size using the `filter branch` command.

I have written a [Ruby gem](https://github.com/bsnape/git-health-check) - which is still in early development - that provides some basic stats about your git repository such as large files in your history (and no longer in your `working copy`) that may be suitable candidates for removal using `filter branch`.

Another option could be to split your single repository into multiple ones. I can't strongly recommend this as I don't know how your code fits together, but there is [a great discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository).

Comment: Yes it is very large repo. `Shallow clone` will not work my requirement as I cannot ignore any history or file depth. I thought of splitting projects into different repos but it needs a huge effort and change. Right now my aim is to be able to `checkout multiple subtrees, push and pull changes`.