# git clone fatal error : RPC failed , The remote end hung up unexpectedly, early EOF

Tags: git, unix

i'm trying to clone a repository and start using it so i tape u

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VirtuOR/OpenTRILL
```

the cloning begins

```
Cloning into 'OpenTRILL'...
remote: Counting objects: 46419, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (42140/42140), done.
```

but it ends with the following error

```
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200MiB | 55 KiB/s    
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Any help please

Answer (score 5):

I know its late but here is the solution,

First,let's do a partial clone to truncate the amount of info coming down:

```
git clone --depth 1 <url>
```

it will clones the repository with the minimum git history. however,cloning with ‘–depth 1′ does not let you push your changed to your remote repo.
Now fetch the rest with :

```
git fetch --depth=1000000
(Update Oct/3/2013) for git version >= 1.8.3,
git fetch --unshallow
```

**note:**

```
‘git fetch –unshallow’ is basically an alias for ‘git fetch –depth=2147483647′.
```

Pushing from a shallow clone isn’t guaranteed; the recommended workflow is to submit a patch(git format-patch) from your shallow clone. Though git clone manual states that a shallow clone cannot push, having a common commit history between your shallow clone and origin will allow the shallow clone to push through. But be warned that your shallow clone will be in trouble if the origin reworks the commit history.[(source article: why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone/6900428#6900428)

Comment: "Pushing from a shallow clone isn’t guaranteed": True. But it will be soon! http://stackoverflow.com/a/21217326/6309

Comment: I get the same error when I do this. "Remote end hung up... early EOF.

Comment: `git fetch --unshallow` wasn't working for me, but adding the remote name and branch worked: `git fetch --unshallow origin branch123`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the issue persists though, because GitHub had some issues today.
See its GitHub status history page:

```
Today
6:52 UTC Everything operating normally.
6:50 UTC Some GitHub pages are again unavailable. We are continuing to investigate.
```

I could cloned your repo (just now) without any glitch, but on Windows, with git1.8.3.

Check if you can upgrade your git version to see if the issue is still present.