# GitHub Clone Error: Cannot clone with EOF error

Tags: git, github, private

I am trying to clone my project from GitHub private repo using Ubuntu 13.04.

I am getting error as below all the time

```
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200| 17 KiB/s      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
```

I have tried the following command as well but not difference

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Is there anything i may be missing? Btw, I am able to clone without problem in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the issue persists, because there were some issues this morning with GitHub.
See its [status history](https://status.github.com/messages):

```
Today
6:52 UTC Everything operating normally.
6:50 UTC Some GitHub pages are again unavailable. We are continuing to investigate.
```

If it does persists, check also if you can reproduce it on different computer/OS.
As shown in [this issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/175), if this really is because of some huge content, then test it with a [shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900428/6309).

Answer (score 2):

I do believe that this is caused by a repository that is too large (because I believe I got the same error when I tried to check out (i.e., clone) a repository that was larger than 1 GB.). That suspicion was also raised by *isherwood* in [*StackOverflow*: Pull large repository (more than 1GB size) over http fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286155/pull-large-repository-more-than-1gb-size-over-http-fail/61880935#61880935)

So, this post here is a copy of the solution I've posted in the before-mentioned link.

1. git clone --depth 1 YOUR-URL-TO-CLONE ./
2. git fetch --unshallow
3. git pull

For more information about the meaning of 1., i.e., a shallow clone, see [*StackOverflow:* Is it safe to shallow clone with --depth 1, create commits, and pull updates again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-it-safe-to-shallow-clone-with-depth-1-create-commits-and-pull-updates-aga)

For more information about the meaning of 2., see [*StackOverflow*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/how-to-convert-a-git-shallow-clone-to-a-full-clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/how-to-convert-a-git-shallow-clone-to-a-full-clone).

Regarding 3: This is, I believe, just to double-check. At least for me that did not bring me any updates.

Comment: This is better as a long-term answer, and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for dolibarr installation on ubuntu server 20.04. Thanks!