# Bitbucket pull/clone error

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting the following errors when trying to setup a repo.

> remote: Counting objects: 516, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100%
>   (382/382), done. error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200 51.00
>   KiB/s      fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

Answer (score 2):

It seems to happen because of problems with  libcurl, which is the underlying library used in http communications in git.

I've read that one of the solutions is to try to increase the http.postBuffer with a command like:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Perhaps take a look at the question: ([GitHub Clone Error: Cannot clone with EOF error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557703)) of zdesam, it seems very related.

Answer (score 0):

There is another fix I found cloning a large repo over networks with big latency (For example cloning an Asia based repo from US). The fix was to use ssh instead of https if the repo allows.

Using the example of cloning from GitHub using commandline GIT
   git clone ssh://git@github.com:jscs-dev/node-jscs.git

Or using SourceTree
[image: Sourcetree clone example]