# fork git repo with clean history - will push work?

Tags: git

I'd like to fork a repo from github to bitbucket with clean history (I do not need and I want to save space). I found out that I can do it with git clone --depth 1 (shallow clone), but my question is if I'll be able to push updates from original repo to the new one?

Comment: According to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone ,with latest version of git (2.5+), it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to go with other solution without `git clone --depth 1` - I was not able to push shallow clone to a new repo on github. I understood that I used a wrong approach.

I created a new branch with no commit history as suggested here: [Make the current commit the only (initial) commit in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15572071/1028256):

```
git branch new_branch_name $(echo "commit message" | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree})
```

and then I pushed it to the new repo as described in this excellent guide: [How to fork a github repository in bitbucket](https://gist.github.com/jcaraballo/1982605):

```
$ git checkout new_branch_name
$ git remote add bb git@bitbucket.org:jcaraballo/test.git
$ git push -u bb new_branch_name
```

So now I have only one branch in the new repo with clean history, and I can exchange updates between the repos via branch `new_branch_name`, merging changes there.