# git shallow cloned repo

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to fork a large repository and I really don't care about most of the history from the upstream repository, just the tips of a couple branches that I want to branch off for my own purposes. Using a shallow clone is sufficient locally but then I can't push it to another repository. I also may need to fetch newer changes from the upstream repository but I will never push my changes upstream.

How can I clone a repository that can be pushed and truncate it to the tips of multiple branches and still be able to merge newer upstream commits without having to reintegrate all the history?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I push from a shallow clone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone)