# Recreate a shallow git repository from GitHub source tarball

Tags: git, github

Somewhat investigative question:

Can one recover a shallow git repository from a GitHub source tarball?

Desired further steps: download only the latest commit object and be able to create and push new commits to the original repo with stock git (of course viewing history wouldn't work because it's not downloaded).

Thanks!

Clarification: one can download the refs, commit trees etc from GitHub api, but wishes to limit the number of requests sufficient for creating and pushing a new commit using standard git client.

Comment: How do you propose to recover that which simply does not exist in the source?

Comment: Does the tarball includes the `.git` directory (where commits, refs and everything is stored)? If yes, recovering the whole history is possible, if not I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: I'm thinking about a source tarball such that GitHub provides, so not refs, commits etc.

The goal is to be able to create a valid commit and push it using stock git, while downloading as few objects as possible through GitHub api.

Comment: Newer versions of git should be able to push from a shallow clone (if both client and server are new enough).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Push shallow clone to a new remote without 'unshallow'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275371/git-push-shallow-clone-to-a-new-remote-without-unshallow)