# Using git to deploy my website without SSH access

Tags: git, ftp, git-commit

I track my website's changes using git. The directory structure is :

```
$ ls my-page 
Gruntfile.js     node_modules     webpage      package.json
```

Of course, I'd like to push only the `webpage` subdirectory contents to the server. Besides, I'd like to ignore the `webpage/assets/sass` subdirectory. My Internet connection is fairly slow, so I'd like the upload to be incremental, or at least upload only the files changed since the last commit. I don't want to upload uncommitted changes.

I know about `git-ftp` but as far as I see from the docs, I can upload only the whole tree with it.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like this because [git doesn't store the deltas (changed files) and each commit contains every file in the repository at that snapshot in time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/4233593).

However, you could [create a shallow clone with just your tip commit and force push that to the remote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6900103/4233593). This would then push the minimum amount of data over the wire through git.

Alternatively, since this is a production environment, then maintaining a version control system is only really useful for emergency rollbacks. So why not simply script a release package? Use something like rsync which would only transfer the modified files, and not the whole repository.