# Git pull or Fetch by fromdate todate

Tags: git, heroku

I am working on 2 remote branches one is `commercial` and other one is `sequential`

now in my app

```
cd myapp

myapp>git remote -v
comercial   https://git.heroku.com/comm.git
sequential  https://git.heroku.com/seq.git
```

Now I want to pull the commits from 1st jan to 28th jan from sequential branch how can I do it

like

```
git pull sequential fromdate todate
```

is it possible?

If it is not possible then only cherrypick is the option or any other option or advice is really appreciable

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [a shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt) and then use [`git fetch --depth` or `--deepen`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---depthltdepthgt) (i.e. instead of dates you use number of commits). But you must understand that [shallow clones are not fully functional clones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6900103/7976758) though [the limitation is being lifted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/7976758).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it would make any sense.

I mean if you have a tree, and you don't pull commits what is not in your range, then it would be 2 trees, not one. Git not meant to track magickal gapes in your commit chain. Also, what would be the benefits you having a chunked part of a 
repository?

If you sure you just need a part of a branch(typically, multiple active release branches related problem), then create a new one, and rebase/cherry-pick the needed commits. But again, you will be missing the "middle" section, so get ready for some fun conflict times.

You can check out a particular commit tho, but you still need to pull all changes, or your directed tree would just be just like twigs, and logs :D

BTW if i may ask: what is your agenda here? Why would you need to pull it like this?

PS: if you want a shallow copy for builds, you can use the --depth with fetch/clone.