# git clone out of memory even with 5.6GB RAM free and 50 GB hard disk

Tags: git

```
 git clone http://vkaul@stash.int.linz.jumio.com/git/BUILD/build-tools.git
cloning into 'build-tools'...
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 2000000000 bytes)
fatal: write error: Invalid argument
```

I know this question was asked before but in that case the workaround was increasing the RAM. Right now it is strange the repository is 2.2GB big and I have 5.5 GB free RAM and 50GB free hard disk. Why will this error occur? Any idea?

Comment: Likely dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7607970/877115. Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1590232/877115. Both list solutions that don't involve increasing RAM.

Comment: I wanted a non scp solution. Given that other people were able to clone and I was unable to do so. Other solutions in the above links are very much RAM and hard drive related, which is not my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration property called packSizeLimit. In my Git installation it is set to 2G by default. Maybe this is also the case with your installation. You can check this by doing

```
git config -l
```

on the command line and look if there is an entry called pack.packSizeLimit. If so, try to increase that value.

Comment: Has that changed since 2011? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7608084/877115) suggests git doesn't look at packSizeLimit

Comment: I did try to increase the packetsizelimit to 4g instead of 2g but it gave me an error in wrong packetsize. Now I changed it to 3g, but it gives the same error.                                       $ git config --global pack.packsizelimit 3g

vkaul@NBVK /c/GIT_build
$ git clone http://vkaul@stash.int.linz.jumio.com/git/BUILD/build-tools.git
Cloning into 'build-tools'...
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 2000000000 bytes)
fatal: write error: Invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue on Windows using [MSysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) 32 bits.
The git 64 bits from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) did the job.
Maybe your local machine in 32 bits and the other server is 64 bits...

My [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516065/938111) is available on question [Git on Windows, “Out of memory - malloc failed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903).

Comment: Please don't create duplicate answers. It's generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/20270). If you think the questions are duplicates, you can [vote to close it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) once you gain enough rep, or [flag it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: You are right @Hasturkun, duplicating the same answer is not a good solution (thanks for the links). These questions are similar but not actually duplicates... I have already reformulated the answer to the current question context. However I have also copy-pasted (duplicated) the linked answer. I my case, a good way to process may be just to put the same answer content (without the copy-paste) within a comment of the question... Or maybe I should more adapt my similar answer to the question context... What about you? Cheers ;)