# GIT svn clone - not enough memory for initialization update-ref error

Tags: git, git-svn, git-clone

I have a problem during performing git svn clone command:

```
git svn clone --trunk="path to specific folder in svn repo" --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt "path to svn repo" /c/tmpRepo
```

Command is working fine by some minutes and then suddenly I am receiving below error:

```
fatal: not enough memory for initializationupdate-ref -m r43274 refs/remotes/origin/trunk c330a7854ebb5f70a729f82c9e301c7ef07b6038: command returned error: 128
```

I tried to clean up my disk space but it didn't help. Does anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891800/git-push-select-not-enough-memory ?

Comment: The error is "*not enough memory*", i.e. it's about RAM, not disk space. Cleaning up disk space shouldn't help. Increasing RAM or virtual memory (swap file) should help.

Comment: @phd thank you for your suggestion. I have increased swap file and it resolved my issue.